# Word for "add value to"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to describe two financial investments that are mutually beneficial, that is, the first investment increases the value of the second, while the second increases the value of the first, what single word can I use in the phrase "reciprocating ______".

It would be the opposite of devaluation, I guess, but somehow no one ever got around to making "envaluation" a word. "Mutally beneficial" doesn't work because it's not specifically pecuniary.

Edit: It's to be used in a heading, so I'm hoping for an "action thing", or, as I just learned, a deverbal noun [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun)]. Like the noun attack from the verb attack, except specifically and solely pecuniary.

Comment: Uh ... augment?

Comment: Could you give an example of the investments?  That might spur some better suggestions

Comment: If you buy a rundown house in a rundown neighborhood and fix it up, it raises not only the value of that house but all the houses around it as well. So, if you buy two houses next to each other and fix them both up, reciprocating envaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, **appreciation** **[in value]**.

> : an increase in the value of something
>
> *He bought the statue because he believed there would be an appreciation in its value.*
>
> *Based on the history of the company, you can expect a significant appreciation in your investment over a number of years.*
>
> *There's been no appreciation in the stock's value.*

[M-W Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/appreciation)

Answer (score 1):

**Growth** is a term that is frequently used to describe gains in the value of a financial asset. While it's not specifically "pecuniary" as you put it, it fits in the phrase you provided:

> > Reciprocating *growth*

**Return**, **yield**, and **gain** are similar alternatives that may work as well.

Comment: I'm using "gain", actually, for now, but hoping for something more active. Thanks

Comment: To some people, reciprocal /reciprocating may suggest that as A grows B diminishes and as B grows A diminishes. How about mutual, synergistic or symbiotic benefit, enhancement, growth.

Answer (score 0):

**[elevate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevate)** ( --> elevation)
1:  to lift up or make higher :  raise  
2:  to raise in rank or status

**[improvement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improvement)**
the act of improving something : the act or process of making something better

I don't know of a solely pecuniary word to fit in there. Maybe you could say *reciprocating financial improvement/elevation*, or something like that.

Comment: I wonder what it says about us that we seem to have so many more words to describe value reduction than value adduction. Oh, wait, adduction is the act of drawing inward toward the median axis of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an analogy from biology:

- symbiosis (n)
- symbiotic (adj)

These have the popular connotation of "mutually beneficial".  Unfortunately, the current biological definition of **symbiosis** encompasses relationships that are NOT mutually beneficial (e.g. parasitic) so the more accepted term among biologists is

- Mutualism (n)
  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mutualism

You didn't say whether a drop in value of one investment also implies a drop in value of the other.  If so, they both move in the same direction in either case, and you could use statistical terms:

- positive correlation
- positively correlated

Answer (score 0):

"Enrichment" strikes me as both useful and situationally-appropriate for you.

Dictionary.com, for instance, lists a definition for "enrich" that says, "to add greater value or significance to".

Mind you, your full term, which would be "reciprocating enrichment", feels somewhat awkward.  You would probably be better-served by something a little more concise, like "symbiosis".